# WSO2 Identity Server - XDAS Auditing

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

The WSO2 Identity Server [features](http://wso2.com/products/identity-server/) list XDAS, but I can't find any more information on how WSO2 uses it.

- Is there any documentation available about how the WSO2 Identity Server uses XDAS?
- Does the Identity Server have an XDAS service API that it can offer auditing services for use by other (external) applications?
- WSO2 offer a Centralized Auditing & Monitoring [solution](http://wso2.com/solutions/security-and-identity-gateway/centralized-auditing-and-monitoring/). How can I set this up for myself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have checked out the whole WSO2 trunk and performed a `find` for files containing XDAS in their filename and a `grep` for files containing XDAS in their contents.  Nothing was found.

My guess is that XDAS has not been implemented in the WSO2 platform.

Answer (score 1):

We have done some work with XDAS in the WSO2 platform and the effort is on hold due to the less demand for XDAS.

You can find additional details from here : http://mail.wso2.org/mailarchive/architecture/2011-February/004868.html